# Connecting two FSRs in Series

Tags: arduino-uno

Does anyone know if i can connect 2 FSR in series and then in parallel to a fixed resistor, creating a potential divider circuit.
Given the inaccuracies and low repeatability of force reading from one FSR, would connecting 2 FSRs in the above arrangement cause even more problems?

Comment: I think you're getting your "series" and "parallel" confused.

Comment: In order to be unambiguous: What is FSR ?

Comment: @tobalt I am assuming (hopefully correctly) Force Sensitive Resistor...

Comment: Please [edit] to add link to FSR datasheet and explanation of what the initialisation stands for.

Comment: What is FSR ?..